# jQuery how to call a function when the div load completes

Tags: jquery

I have a page where i will have many buttons and links.

On clicking of the buttons and links, i have a div tag called "scriptWPQ2" which will refresh.

On refresh of this div completes, i need to write a function to change some data in the div dynamically.

At the moment i tried document.ready or window.load it does not help

please enlighten me on this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#scriptWPQ2').load(function () {

        //dosomething

    });
});
```

Comment: Are you asking for changes on onload event and you've mentioned onclick event. Can you please clear this doubt?

Comment: @strikingknife what do you mean by "div tag called "scriptWPQ2" which will refresh." ?, are those button and links binding or calling any function whihc effect this div?

Answer (score 0):

## Callback Function [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and this is set to each DOM element in turn.

```
/* 
 * load
 */
$("#scriptWPQ2").load("action/test.html", function() {
  //dosomething
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

## Callback Function [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) , [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

It does not require a delay in microseconds for experiencing feedback. Such a function does not contain.

```
/* 
 * html
 */
$("#scriptWPQ2").html("<div>Static entry.</div>");

/* 
 * text
 */    
$("#scriptWPQ2").text("Static entry.");

/* 
 * append
 */
$("#scriptWPQ2").append("<p>Static entry.</p>");
```

### To check changes

You should run a separate function when the button(s) is clicked.

```
$("button").on('click',divChangeTrigger);

function divChangeTrigger(){
    //dosomething
}
```